# powershell iterate all users and display recent lnk files

Tags: powershell

Iterate all windows `$users` and display the recent .lnk files from a specific path!

I have tried importing this module - https://gist.github.com/picheljitsu/cc2ed99cbae7caad3abb0928cd8a286b

Get-RecentFiles and I want to iterate with $users after getting the users with get-localuser

```
$user = (Get-LocalUser | Select-Object Name) |
        ForEach-Object  { Get-RecentFiles $user }
```

should display recent files of all users recent directory..

```
Directory: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                           
d-----        6/30/2019   6:59 PM                AutomaticDestinations                          
d-----         7/1/2019   3:21 PM                CustomDestinations    

 Directory: C:\Users\user2\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                           
----                -------------         ------ ----                                           
d-----        6/30/2019   6:59 PM                AutomaticDestinations                          
d-----         7/1/2019   3:21 PM                CustomDestinations
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what is your question.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `Get-LocalUser | Select-Object Name` is an array of users. When you pass this array to the pipeline, it will "unwrap" its items and pass them one at a time, and this item will be declared as `$_` variable.

> [Passing Arrays to Pipeline](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/passing-arrays-to-pipeline)
>
> If a function returns more than one value, PowerShell wraps them in an array. However, if you pass the results to another function inside a pipeline, the pipeline automatically "unwraps" the array and processes one array element at a time.

`ExpandProperty` parameter is used to convert the object property `Name` to string to be used in the `Get-RecentFiles` function.

**Modify your code and try this:**

```
Get-LocalUser | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Foreach-Object {Get-RecentFiles $_}
```

**Update**
The above code will get some errors for the disabled users (e.g: administrator, guest). To solve this, you have to only get the enabled users as follows:

```
Get-LocalUser | Where-Object Enabled | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Foreach-Object {Get-RecentFiles $_}
```

Comment: It's working fine though after completing throws up an error `Get-RecentFiles : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'UserName'. The "test-path "C:\Users\$_"" 
validation script for the argument with value "WDAGUtilityAccount" did not return a result of True. 
Determine why the validation script failed, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:86
+ ... ect-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Foreach-Object {Get-RecentFiles $_}`

Comment: yeah i know. `Get-LocalUser` gets the local user accounts, and `Get-RecentFiles` tests the directory to that user in C:\users; However, not every user has directory in C:\Users (e.g: administrator, guest), so the module `Get-RecentFiles` through this error for the users who don't have directory in C:\Users

Comment: But you should still have some real result displayed for the users like `$env:username`